# Omitting the auxiliary verb in short answers or titles

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, clipping

Please help me in this.

what do we call the composition of the short sentence below, where there's no auxiliary verb:

**Request approved.**

(subject + past participle)

and which of the following gives the same meaning?

The request got approved.

The request has been approved.

The request is approved.

Comment: The auxiliary verbs may be omissible regarding to style of your context, styles that are often used in magazines headline, reports , warnings and etc. As you may know, many languages around the globe doesn't have an exact word for the verb BE, because BE doesn't have discernible meaning on it's own, so it may be omitted when you just want to give the terms as clearly as possible.

Comment: Not mentioned yet here or in the link is Telegraph style: wording shortened for special reasons. The notice sign, road sign, and telegraph style all have economy in common, but differently. The telegraph charges per letter, so space is not limited, but comes with a cost that taught us to how to economize. Notice signs often became rubber stamps (Request Approved), a space limitation. .Road signs economize space to economize time to put the driver's eyes back on the road quickly.

Comment: This is called a bare passive.